# Equivalent to @dataProvider annotation for unit testing Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

PHPUnit has a useful feature for testing code with a data set of inputs and expected outputs with the [@dataProvider test method annotation](http://www.jblotus.com/2014/01/29/use-dataprovider-to-reduce-duplication-and-improve-the-maintainability-of-your-tests/).

I'm using [JS-Test-Driver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/js-test-driver) to write unit tests for javascript. Am I correct in saying it has no similar feature? How should bulk input/output data be tested in Javascript?

Comment: So you create a new class, just to pass a function to the test-framework, right? then, you need this class to extend some `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` to provide you some utility-methods. And now you want to annotate this function with a comment to tell the framework where how to generate the arguments for the function you passed. Well as a JS-developer all this bloat doesn't make sense to me; therefore this "feature" doesn't make sense to me. I'd build the Array of arguments for the tests and then `testCases.forEach(testArgs => myTest(...testArgs))`, or something like that.

Comment: @Thomas thanks - I had a feeling it wouldn't make sense for JS for one reason or another. It would be brilliant if you could elaborate on your suggestion in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the [Parameterize plugin](https://github.com/AStepaniuk/qunit-parameterize).

The test would then look like this:

```
QUnit
    .cases([
        { a : 2, b : 2, expectedSum : 4 },
        { a : 5, b : 5, expectedSum : 10 },
        { a : 40, b : 2, expectedSum : 42 }
    ])
    .test("Sum test", function(params) {
        var actualSum = sum(params.a, params.b);
        equal(actualSum, params.expectedSum);
    });
```